# Web Scraping a table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch the calendar of events of current month and store it into the file in the same format, such as, date, time, event and location) from my school's website https://www.umkc.edu/calendar/

I don't have much experience in HTML so I don't really know what I am dealing with, that's why I used iframe, but I don't even know if it's the right thing.

Can you help me with getting the table that has the events?

That's what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.umkc.edu/calendar/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("iframe"))
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: And what happens with your code versus what should happen?

Comment: I am getting irrelevant data, while I should be getting the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, data is dynamically added. You could use the same request as is performed for iframe content and use regex (or split) to get out the required javascript to then parse with hjson (due to unquoted keys); extract the html content and parse with bs4. The alternative, shown at bottom is to investigate the rss feed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re, hjson
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.trumba.com/s.aspx?calendar=UMKC&widget=main&srpc.cbid=trumba.spud.4&srpc.get=true')
p = re.compile(r'requestComplete\((.*)\);', re.DOTALL)
data = hjson.loads(re.sub('\r+|\n+|\t+','', p.findall(r.text)[0].strip()))
soup = bs(data['body'],'lxml')
p2 = re.compile(r"'(.*?)'", re.DOTALL)
results  = []

for tr in soup.select('.twSimpleTableTable tr')[2:]:
    date = tr.select_one('.twStartDate').text
    time = tr.select_one('td:has(.twStartDate) + td, .twStartTime').text
    event = p2.findall(tr.select_one('.txVMid')['title'])[0].strip()
    location = tr.select_one('.twLocation')
    if location is None:
        location = ''
    else:
        location = ' '.join([string for string in location.stripped_strings])
    row = [date, time, event, location]
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

---

Or (this needs further investigation and work):

```
import requests, re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.trumba.com/calendars/UMKC.rss')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
df = pd.DataFrame(zip([i.text for i in soup.select('title')]
                 ,[i.text for i in soup.select('link')]
                 ,[re.sub('<br />|<br/>','',i.text) for i in soup.select('description')]))
print(df)
```